# Why does localstorage store the wrong value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, storage

I am a newbie with a localstorage issue. I have a few dependent dropdowns that are loaded via ajax from a server. When the user makes a selection the localstorage stores the wrong value...the last value. From my research I thought that .map() may be a solution to my problem but being a newbie I am not familiar with the syntax and I have not been able to get it to work. Can anyone figure out what is causing this problem? Is .map() the correct solution? Here is a photo of what I am having an issue with.
[image]

Here is the code

```
    $('.country').on('change', function () {
        var countryId = $(this).val();            
        var state_select = $(this).closest('form').find('.state');
        var city_select = $(this).closest('form').find('.city');            

        if (countryId) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON', 
                url: 'ajaxData3.php',
                data: {
                    country_id: countryId
                },                     
                success: function (r) {
                    console.log('States', r);

                    $(state_select).html('<option value="" selected="selected">State</option>');
                    $(city_select).html('<option value="" selected="selected">City </option>');

                    if (r.status) {
                        r.data.forEach(function (state) {
                            $(state_select).append(`<option value="${state.id}">${state.name}</option>`);

                            $('.state').each(function(r) {
                                var stateList = $(state);
                                var thisSelection = $(this);
                                var thisId = thisSelection.attr('id');
                                var storageId = 'state-' + thisId;
                                var storedInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageId));                                


                                thisSelection.change(function(i) {                                   
                                    var selectedOptions = []; // create an array to hold all currently selected options 

                                    thisSelection.find('option:selected').each(function(i) {
                                        var thisOption = $(this);
                                        selectedOptions.push(thisOption.val());                                           
                                    });

                                    localStorage.setItem(storageId, JSON.stringify(state.name));                                       

                                })                                  

                            })

                        })

                    } else {

                        $(state_select).html('<option value="" selected="selected">Unavailable </option>');
                        $(city_select).html('<option value="" selected="selected">Unavailable </option>');
                    }

                }
            })
        };
```

Here is the markup

```
         <form id="form1" autocomplete="off">
    <select id="country1" class="country" name="country">
        <?php include("countryAjaxData.php"); ?> 
    </select> 
    <select id="state1" class="state" name="state">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select state</option>
    </select> 
    <select id="city1" class="city" name="city">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select city</option> 
    </select>
</form>
<form id="form2" autocomplete="off">
    <select id="country2" class="country" name="country">
        <?php include("countryAjaxData.php"); ?> 
    </select> 
    <select id="state2" class="state" name="state">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select state</option>
    </select> 
    <select id="city2" class="city" name="city">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select city</option> 
    </select>
</form>
<form id="form3" autocomplete="off">
    <select id="country3" class="country" name="country">
        <?php include("countryAjaxData.php"); ?> 
    </select> 
    <select id="state3" class="state" name="state">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select state</option>
    </select> 
    <select id="city3" class="city" name="city">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select city</option> 
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Not exactly related, but what is the purpose of `window.load = $(document).ready(...);`? `.ready` returns a HTMLDocument object, and `load` is just a custom property of `window`.

Comment: I need to put my getItem into the code eventually. For some reason localstorage won't load the values into a dropdown otherwise... from my research and from what I have tried. I have removed it since it is distracting from my original question.

Comment: The extra circular reference to the window seems quite useless, just `$(document).ready(...);` would do.

Comment: I would suspect the values coming from the server. Are you sure they are correct? Try placing a breakpoint on the line where you set the localstorage and check the value of state.name

Comment: @Chimera the values that the user selects in the dropdown are correct (please see photo). The localstorage is automatically storing the last value within the list of states even though you can clearly see that the dropdown has the actual value that the user selected. If the state dropdown list only has one state in it, then it is also by default the last state as well as the selected state....if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to post the answer so others can see. Hopefully someone here on stackoverflow will take the time to help me next time. This 'voting', 'points' and 'badge' thing gets in the way of actual learning.

The forEach() reiterates the function each time it is called. So the last entry will be where the reiteration completes. The localStorage.setItem needs to be moved into a .change() function or .on('change', function()) and the value needs to be .text() to simply read the text that was displayed.

```
    localStorage.setItem('yourkeyhere', JSON.stringify($(this).text()));
```